# OutOfMemoryError in my ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

So I am trying to write a simple code to put all of the names from an object that has both names and descriptions stored in it.  I want this so I can use it in a autocomplete text box later on.  When running my code I am getting the below error.  I am only loading roughly 26 strings into this code so I can't believe I am really running out of memory at this point, so i'm guessing is inefficient code.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllFartsNames(ArrayList<Farts> farray) {
    ArrayList<String> FartsNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count=0;
    while (count<farray.size()){
        FartsNameArray.add(farray.get(count).name);
    }

    return FartsNameArray;
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shweber.lanternkeeper, PID: 2492
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
    at com.example.shweber.lanternkeeper.MainActivity.getAllFartsNames(MainActivity.java:138)
    at com.example.shweber.lanternkeeper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I don't run this function my code works fine.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment your count

```
int count=0;
while (count<farray.size()){
    FartsNameArray.add(farray.get(count).name);
    count++;
}
```

You can also use a `for` loop too

```
for(int count = 0; count < farray.size(); count++) {
    FartsNameArray.add(farray.get(count).name);
}
```

Or a `foreach`

```
foreach(Farts f in farray){
    FartsNameArray.add(f.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's been a while since I've done much coding, I'll be kicking myself for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Do the increment inline:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllFartsNames(ArrayList<Farts> farray) {
    ArrayList<String> FartsNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count=0;
    while (count<farray.size()){
        FartsNameArray.add(farray.get(count++).name);
    }

    return FartsNameArray;
}
```

Comment: That will get index 1, not 0, for the first iteration.

Comment: The index happens after the operation, thus the first count == 0

Comment: Well, I'll be darned. I just tested it and you're right. +1 for teaching me something new.

Comment: Schweeet! Thanks @ChrisStillwell! Also if you do ++count, then 1 will be added before the operation.

Answer (score 1):

i think you forgot to increment your count;

```
while (count<farray.size()){
    FartsNameArray.add(farray.get(count).name);
    count++;
}
```